# ubuntu kylin 14.04 display problem

Tags: 14.04, display, kylin

I've just installed UBUNTU kylin 14.04 and when I enter to desktop my screen is full of vertical colored lines.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is hardware specific, without knowing your hardware information it is impossible to help.

First of all, have you fully updated your system?

If the problem persists after you have done a system update, you are highly suggested to report a bug at Launchpad. If you have not done so before, please read the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs, the command to report bugs is called '`ubuntu-bug`'.